# A function is not a function

Tags: javascript, function

While using the console in the embedded Chrome PDF viewer, I realized `document.all` unexpectedly includes a function in the list it returned.

```
> [].filter.call(document.all, function(e){return typeof e === "function"})
< [function anonymous()]
```

However, trying to execute this function will yield an error saying it is not a function.

[image]

Why does this happen? Is it possible to create a function that cannot be executed?

Comment: Derek's reaction after this is same as his avatar.

Comment: That element is a `HTMLEmbedElement`, and this is the behavior of `object` and `embed` tags. I don't know what the history of them being callable is, but there are other host functions (mainly constructors) that are not callable.

Comment: @AlexanderO'Mara Nice find. So it is caused by the `<embed>` tag implementing `[[Call]]` and as the spec states, `typeof` should return `"function"`.

Comment: Indeed, but I wonder why these tags implement `[[Call]]`. I'm guessing for historical reasons, but I don't know what those would be.

Comment: @AlexanderO'Mara Since they are callable objects, why doesn't `foo()` work then?

Comment: That's the thing, they implement `[[Call]]`, but apparently aren't callable. Unfortunately I don't know the history about why this might be.